# Full Join and sum 2 queries in access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am very new to this type of complicated joins and summing functions.
I had 2 table queries which have same fields `(i.e: ProdID, ProdName, NetQty, Unit)`
The 1st one query contains *OpStock* and the 2nd one contains *Purchase*.

I want to add this 2 table query to make a single table so that I can able to see current stock.

The data looks like this for 1 st table is:

```
ProdID ProdName Qty
100 Rose     700
101 Lilly    550
103 Jasmine  600
105 Lavender 400
```

The data looks like this for 2nd table is:

```
ProdID ProdName Qty
100 Rose     400
101 Lilly    250
104 Lotus   1000
106 MariGold 400
```

The final data looks like this for 3rd table is:

```
ProdID ProdName Qty
100 Rose     1100
101 Lilly     800
103 Jasmine   600
104 Lotus    1000
105 Lavender  400
106 MariGold  400
```

How can i achieve this one using sql for access2003.
Thanks.

I am very sorry Ciaran,
This is purely access used for vb.net
Here Is my access query1

```
SELECT sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdID,
       sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdName,
       Sum(([sp_OpenIandP_Prod.SumOfNetQty]-[sp_OpenSales_Prod.SumOfNetQty])) AS NetQty,
       sp_OpenIandP_Prod.UnitSName
FROM sp_OpenIandP_Prod 
     INNER JOIN sp_OpenSales_Prod ON sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdID=sp_OpenSales_Prod.ProdID
GROUP BY sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdID, 
         sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdName, 
         sp_OpenIandP_Prod.UnitSName;
```

The 1st query result would be like this:

```
ProdID  ProdName    NetQty  UnitSName
1   Rose            0   Kgs
2   Lilly       7125    Mts
3   Lotus       12374   Nos
```

The second query is:

```
SELECT Products.ProdID, Products.ProdName,
       Sum(OPDDetails.NetQty) AS SumOfNetQty, Units.UnitSName
FROM Units 
     INNER JOIN (Products 
         INNER JOIN (Brands 
             INNER JOIN OPDDetails ON Brands.BrID=OPDDetails.BrandID)
         ON Products.ProdID=Brands.ProdID) 
     ON Units.UnitID=Products.UnitID
WHERE (((OPDDetails.PurID)>0) 
  AND ((OPDDetails.OPDDate)>=[StartDate] And (OPDDetails.OPDDate)<=[EndDate]))
GROUP BY Products.ProdID, Products.ProdName, Units.UnitSName;
```

and the result set would be like this:

```
ProdID  ProdName    SumOfNetQty UnitSName
1   Rose    1800    Kgs
2   Lilly   21000   Mts
```

I got the above result easily.
But it is not as much easy to get like this:

```
ProdID  ProdName    SumOfNetQty UnitSName
1   Rose    1800    Kgs
2   Lilly   28125   Mts
3       Lotus   12374   Nos
```

That's all.  Thanks again.

Comment: can you post the 2 queries you used?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a vb.net question, however you need to use a UNION

```
Select ProdId, ProdName, Sum(Qty) As QtySum
  From (Select ProdId, ProdName, Qty From TableA
        Union All
        Select ProdId, ProdName, Qty From TableB) DerrivedView
 Group By ProdId, ProdName
```

Comment: Thanks Ciaran,

I just make a mistake and yours is great help.
And I am searching for this for 2 days and above.

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UNION between your 2 queries then group by product:

```
SELECT ProdID, ProdName, Sum(NetQty) As NetQty, UnitSName
FROM 
( 

    SELECT sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdID,
           sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdName,
           Sum(([sp_OpenIandP_Prod.SumOfNetQty]-[sp_OpenSales_Prod.SumOfNetQty])) AS NetQty,
           sp_OpenIandP_Prod.UnitSName
    FROM sp_OpenIandP_Prod 
         INNER JOIN sp_OpenSales_Prod ON sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdID=sp_OpenSales_Prod.ProdID
    GROUP BY sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdID, 
             sp_OpenIandP_Prod.ProdName, 
             sp_OpenIandP_Prod.UnitSName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Products.ProdID, Products.ProdName,
           Sum(OPDDetails.NetQty) AS NetQty, Units.UnitSName
    FROM Units 
         INNER JOIN (Products 
             INNER JOIN (Brands 
                 INNER JOIN OPDDetails ON Brands.BrID=OPDDetails.BrandID)
             ON Products.ProdID=Brands.ProdID) 
         ON Units.UnitID=Products.UnitID
    WHERE (((OPDDetails.PurID)>0) 
      AND ((OPDDetails.OPDDate)>=[StartDate] And (OPDDetails.OPDDate)<=[EndDate]))
    GROUP BY Products.ProdID, Products.ProdName, Units.UnitSName

)
GROUP BY ProdID, ProdName, UnitSName
```